# How to find duplicates in list according to specific attribute

Tags: list, linq, duplicates

I have this list :  `List<manageMonthly> smsMngrDataMonthly = new List<manageMonthly>();`

```
{"BILL","321"}{"RUTH","222"}{"DAVID","321"}{"ANNA","111"}
```

the class is :

```
public class manageMonthly
{
    public string FullNameMonthly { get; set; }  
    public string AssetNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get all the duplicate objects according to asset number - Bill and David, I tried a few examples of linq that I found online but all weren't working (I got nulls)
for example -

```
 var duplicatesa = smsMngrDataMonthly.GroupBy(x => x.AssetNumber).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
 var duplicatesb = smsMngrDataMonthly.GroupBy(x => x.AssetNumber).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: _"(I got nulls)"_ - where exactly did you get nulls?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: @GuruStron the vars : duplicatesa and duplicatesb were nulls.

Comment: Those variables would *never* be null. The result of `Any` is a bool, and the result of `Where` is never null - but it might be an empty sequence. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me. Maybe the trouble is in how you use the result from the grouping? In doing a `SelectMany` you can show each of the duplicate managers.

```
List<ManageMonthly> smsMngrDataMonthly = new List<ManageMonthly> {
    new ManageMonthly {FullNameMonthly = "BILL", AssetNumber = "321"},
    new ManageMonthly {FullNameMonthly = "RUTH", AssetNumber = "222"},
    new ManageMonthly {FullNameMonthly = "DAVID",AssetNumber = "321"},
    new ManageMonthly {FullNameMonthly = "ANNA", AssetNumber = "111"}};
    
var dups = smsMngrDataMonthly
    .GroupBy(x => x.AssetNumber)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
    
dups.SelectMany(d => d)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.FullNameMonthly));
```

This returns:

```
BILL 
DAVID
```